# Wake on LAN (WOL) using domain name instead of IP

Tags: wake-on-lan

I can succesfully wake my server over the WAN or LAN using WOL.

However, I have a dynamic IP, so to get it up from WAN I need to ssh into the router using a dyndns subdomain, then check router the IP and then send a WOL magic packet, or login to the dyndns account and see what the current IP is. This is all rather tiresome…

Why can't I use the dyndns subdomain directly? I couldn’t find a program that would allow me to do this. Any ideas how to deal with this problem?

I'm looking for a program that will allow me to send magic packets using domain name instead of IP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WOL - Wake On Lan over internet](http://superuser.com/questions/266009/wol-wake-on-lan-over-internet)

Comment: has nothing to do with that. my question is simple, can I use domain instead of IP address.

Comment: Sandro, DNS resolution is something that happens at the source - it has nothing to do with the configuration of your router.  So if your dyndns account is resolving correctly, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dyndns name should resolve to the public IP of your router, so this shouldn't be a problem.

If you can use the dyndns address to connect to the router than this makes even less sense.

You should try to resolve the dyndns address:

```
nslookup yourname.dyndns.org
```

It **should** resolve to the same IP address as the one you pull from your router. If it doesn't than sometime is wrong with the dyndns setup (although I can't imagine what it is, unless you have multiple public IP addresses).

Usually, the name would be resolved to an IP address **before** any package is sent. So this shouldn't make any difference as long as the dyndns entry is updated.

Comment: that's what I was thinking. but I cannot find program to that sends magic packet via domain instead of IP. All of them error out, so i was thinking there could be a reason non of them thought of including it as a feature.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: Is the dyndns address resolved to the correct IP address? Otherwise, the problem is with the WOL application. The application assumes it is always used on a LAN and, thus, has no DNS support maybe. In that case, just resolve the dyndns address **locally**. There is no need to connect to your router to get its public address.

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of the OP was to avoid having to manually get the IP and paste it into the wol app -- they asked for an app which allowed specifying his (DDNS) fqdn instead of the numeric IP

Answer (score 2):

Try setting up a nat rule for UDP port 7 and/or 9 that goes from the router to the target pc - see if that works!

This could be a security hole, so, I wouldn't recommend it - but, I am pretty sure the problem is the firewall.

Comment: What do UDP ports 7 and 9 have to do with that? WOL packets are sent as a simple broadcast, so you can't even add a NAT rule – what would the destination of that NAT rule be if the target device has no IP?

Comment: The UDP ports matter in my case, because sending it across subnets and needing IPhelper rules to send these from one specific subnet between routers of the other various subnets --> https://superuser.com/questions/295325/does-it-matter-what-udp-port-a-wol-signal-is-sent-to

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on [Oliver Salzburg's answer](https://superuser.com/a/429371/461558):

`wakeonlan -i $(nslookup your.domain.net | awk -F': ' 'NR==6 { print $2 } ') MM:AA:CC:AA:DD:RR`

Answer (score 0):

```
wakeonlan -i $(dscacheutil -q host -a name yourdomain.com | awk -F': ' 'NR==2 { print $2 } ') MM:AA:CC:AA:DD:RR
```

Substitute the DNS name (yourdomain.com) and MAC address (MM:AA:CC:AA:DD:RR) with yours.
Also it might be necessary to change `NR==2` with another number of `awk` results. You can test it preliminary with executing `dscacheutil -q host -a name yourdomain.com` to check which result line you need.

Comment: It needs more information and description.